# Background image for frame title

Tags: beamer, graphics, backgrounds

Using `beamer`, how can I insert a background image under the title of each frame?
I could insert an image but the result was that the title disappeared because the image is over it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `\addtobeamertemplate` command to add the image to every frame in which the `\frametitle` command is used. You only add the image to the `frametitle` template. A simple example using the `textpos` package to control the placement of the image:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textpos}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{
\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(-10pt,0pt)
\includegraphics[width=.9\paperwidth,height=1cm]{onebit_29}
\end{textblock*}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some long title to overlap the included image}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could add the image as part of the frame title argument, e.g. using

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\rlap{\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{image}}}Your frame title}
     ...

\end{frame}
```

(The `\frametitle` is optional in this case.)

This inserts and scales a background image under the frame title. You might also want to add the option `width=\textwidth` (or a similar width).

Alternatively try `\adjustbox{bgimage=<image>}{Your frame title}` from the `adjustbox` package instead of the frame title alone.

Comment: it works fine in plain style. But I found out that it overwrites the default color background if I use theme **Madrid**. Is there any way to replace instead of overwrite it?